# Increment user defined variable in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, load-testing, jsr223

I have a register REST service to be tested for performance. only required parameter mobilenumber has to be changed for every loop/thread request

How can I increment my User defined variable (by increment value stored as another udv) while threading/looping to multiple tests as a part of load test.

Trying to have a jsr 233 pre-processor for all successful register requests

I don't want to use csv as I have only one parameter to be changed

I am reading about var.get() and vars.put() functions which can be used but not getting thorugh it correctly.

---

Trying the following code - the log in shown below the code

```
log.info("Before execution")
log.info("${mobileNumber}") // my udv mobileNumber
log.info("${increment}") // my udv increment value

inc = ${increment}

long number = Long.parseLong(vars.get("mobileNumber"))

number = number + inc

log.info("Incremented number")
log.info(String.valueOf(number))

vars.put("mobileNumber", String.valueOf(number))

log.info("After Execution")
log.info("${mobileNumber}")
```

Log :

```
2014/11/25 09:25:26 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Dummy services 1-1 
2014/11/25 09:25:26 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler: Before execution 
2014/11/25 09:25:26 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler: 9990000000 
2014/11/25 09:25:26 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler: 1000 
2014/11/25 09:25:26 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler: Incremented number 
2014/11/25 09:25:26 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler: 9990001000 
2014/11/25 09:25:26 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler: After Execution 
2014/11/25 09:25:26 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler: 9990000000 
2014/11/25 09:25:26 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Dummy services 1-1
```

As per log, Increment is successful but the vars.put() is not successful ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given than mobile numbers can be up to 15 digits long you need to use Long Java class.

Assuming that your UDV holding mobile number is "number" you can use the following code snippet:

```
long number = Long.parseLong(vars.get("number")); 
number = number + 1;
vars.put("number", String.valueOf(number));
```

You can also consider using [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) JMeter Function to generate random number of any length (the function uses String representation).

For extra information on `vars`, `ctx` and other JMeter API objects exposes to scripting-enabled test elements refer to [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Comment: Missing something in my script, added details in the question.

Comment: Your script works fine, perhaps there is an issue in JSR223 Sampler. If you add a Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener after your JSR223 Sampler you'll see that your `mobileNumber` variable gets incremented http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf5XI.png

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) for debugging techniques, tips and tricks

Comment: I think it is something to do with how JMeter uses the variables.
I am not getting the incremented value using ${varName} but getting it using vars.get("varName"). May be ${} uses some pre-populated values to be used for the thread. Thanks for helping me with it.

Answer (score 1):

If we are updating a JMeter variable we cannot access the updated value using ${varName} format (Not sure of Reasons). I successfully got the updated value using vars.get("varName"} function.

```
log.info("Before execution")
log.info("${mobileNumber}") // my udv mobileNumber
log.info("${increment}") // my udv increment value

inc = ${increment}

long number = Long.parseLong(vars.get("mobileNumber"))

number = number + inc

log.info("Incremented number")
log.info(String.valueOf(number))

vars.put("mobileNumber", String.valueOf(number))

log.info("After Execution")
log.info("${mobileNumber}")
log.info(vars.get("mobileNumber"))
```

Log:

```
2014/11/26 09:16:06 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler: After Execution 
2014/11/26 09:16:06 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler: 8762200000 
2014/11/26 09:16:06 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler: 8762201000
```

Thnaks for help Dmtri and olyv

Answer (score 0):

I usually use BSFPre(Post)processor + Groovy. In this case it would look like

```
i = ${YOUR_UDV}
i += 1
vars.putObject("YOUR_UDV", i.toString())
```

Comment: I have to use long as the mobile number is 10 digit and cannot fit int. Trying the code as updated in the question still not getting expected results - refer the question updated.

Answer (score 0):

Universal inc long variable:

```
long number = Long.parseLong(vars.get(Parameters)); 
number = number + 1;
vars.put(Parameters, String.valueOf(number));
```

Parameters: Variable name

[image: inc long variable with Groovy]